# Why my selenium IDE works good while the same python command doesn't?

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I have some problems trying to automate repetitive tasks in my company's intranet website.

While I can properly find elements in other websites (clicking, sending keys etc.), I can't do the same in this website (the error I always get is "*unable to find element with xpath* == ... ").

I tried to do **the same tasks** recording them with Selenium IDE, and it works well.

If I export the Selenium IDE test case as python code and I compare the xpath command with mine, the xpath is the same, and it's the same that I get using the firefox selector to the point I want to click.

Since for other reasons I must work with explorer (so I have the explorer webdriver etc.), I haven't tried to run the code with python+(webdriver for Firefox).

*Code:*

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver=webdriver.IE("D:\myfolder\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
base_url="https://companywebsite.ext")
driver.get(base_url)    #it's ok until now, I can open the webpage
time.sleep(20)
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]")
time.sleep(10)
```

Here are my questions:

1) Why can I do things right in other websites and not in this?

2) Why Selenium IDE is able to do that and, with the same commands, it doesn't work with my python script?

3) Do I have to do particular setups?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your companies website written in Angular? if so you should try using wait for elements

Comment: Thank you, Moshe.
I think it's not written in Anguar, because if I search for angular elements in the browser console, I can't find anything.

Comment: have you tried using IE driver for other websites?

Comment: Yes, and it works well. I tried in Facebook, Linkedin etc.: I succeeded in clicking links or sending keys to forms.
Do you have any idea of what can be the problem?

Comment: In case I want to wait that something happens in the page, as you suggested talking about angular elements, which kind of commands should I use? Is a general time.sleep command enough to achieve that?

Comment: the more elegant way (best practice) is to use `wait`s hear is the documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: in your xPath, you should be using a more robust path like id's or CSS selectors

Comment: have you resolved this issue? did you see the answers given?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `wait`'s:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver=webdriver.IE("D:\myfolder\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
base_url="https://companywebsite.ext")
driver.get(base_url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]")))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, for helping, really.
Now the traceback changed in TimeoutException, like if it still has problems in finding the element. The strange thing is that the selenium ide works, and if you export it as python code the xpath is the same!

By the way, I can add some infos: the page contains a table where the rows correspond to different profiles; in the HTML, I found some "onclick" commands: they are one for every profile, and they appear like `<tr onclick='document.forms.namedItem("a1").submit()'>`
Do you think this can be useful to simulate the mouse clicking on one of them?

Comment: yes! you can add `driver.execute_script("your JS to simulate clicking")`

Comment: So in this case I should try something like:
`driver.execute_script("document.forms.namedItem("a1").submit()")` ?
Thanks!

Comment: that should work! you can just click on the elements that need clicking... with selenium!

Comment: Thank you a lot, Moshe. I tried all day long, but it still doesn't work.
It seems like something is crypted in this page, I don't know: I can't find anyting with the usual commands. Moreover, the only onclick command that I can activate is a link to the homepage...
I'm too inexpert in js, maybe...or maybe there is something hidden.